# Entity Framework responds slow, but generated query runs fast in the SqlDeveloper worksheet

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework

I have 3 tables in the Oracle 12c database.

1. `MainTable(Id number, Table1_Id number, Table2_Id number)`
2. `Table1(Id number, Registration_Date date, Kind_Id number)`
3. `Table2(Id number, Pin)`

So I wrote the following code peace using entity framework:

```
dbContext.Set<MainTable>
         .Where(mt => mt.Table2.Pin == pin && pd.Table1.KindId == kindValue)
         .Select(pd => new { pd.Id, pd.Table1.RegistrationDate })
         .ToList();
```

In this statement type of `pin` variable is `string` and type of `kindValue` is `int`. When I run this code EF generates the following query:

```
Opened connection at 11-Mar-19 14:31:05 +04:00

SELECT 
"Extent1"."ID" AS "ID", 
"Extent3"."REGISTRATION_DATE" AS "REGISTRATION_DATE"
FROM   "SCHEMA_NAME"."MAIN_TABLE" "Extent1"
INNER JOIN "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE2" "Extent2" ON "Extent1"."TABLE2_ID" = "Extent2"."ID"
INNER JOIN "SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE1" "Extent3" ON "Extent1"."TABLE1_ID" = "Extent3"."ID"
WHERE ((("Extent2"."PIN" = :p__linq__0) OR (1 = 0)) AND ("Extent3"."KIND_ID" = :p__linq__1))

-- p__linq__0: '7E998YT' (Type = Object)
-- p__linq__1: '1' (Type = Int32, IsNullable = false)
-- Executing at 11-Mar-19 14:31:05 +04:00
-- Completed in 5822 ms with result: OracleDataReader

Closed connection at 11-Mar-19 14:31:11 +04:00
```

When I execute this query in the `SQL Developer worksheet` then query gives result in `0.0032` seconds, but EF executes `5.822` seconds. I don't understand why this happens. Anyone can explain why this execution time difference occurs?

Another interesting thing is EF generates `OR (1 = 0)` condition in the query. What is my mistake?

Comment: Maybe SQL developer has the connection already opened but EF does open the connection + execute the SQL?. Anyway 5.8 seconds opening the connection seems huge... Your `p__linq__0` parameter being `Type = Object` seems weird. Is your variable `pin` a string?

Comment: @bradbury9, I have other queries that execute under 50 milliseconds.
Yes my `p__linq__0` is `string`

Comment: Edit your question and add the declaration of the `pin` and `kindValue` variables.

Comment: @bradbury9 I updated quession and added information about variables

Comment: Looks like it does not recognize the `Pin` column datatype and providing to the Oracle a wrong datatype (Object instead of String) and Oracle is taking time doing the casting/conversion. If possible I would suggest you changing the EF info to make the `Pin` property string.

Comment: How many rows are returned? If 'lots' is there a FETCH parameter/property you can set in Linq similar to JDBC `setFetchSize ` to reduce round tripping? If only a few rows are returned then maybe not appplicable.

Comment: @TenG 2 rows returned

Comment: Well object relation mappers can be slow converting SQL records into Objects especially if the framework seams to be using [reflection api](https://www.google.com/search?q=entity-framework+reflection+api) to do it..  But 5 second overhead seams indeed to much for only 2 records..

Comment: Thank you guys! Your comments helped me to find the answer.

Comment: @RaymondNijland is not the number of rows returned, but the casting over all the table rows. If the table is big, a wrong casting would take time. Based on the amount of time I would suggest a pretty big table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments to the quession I added `.HasColumnType("VARCHAR2")` configuration using fluent api as follows:

```
Property(m => m.Pin)
   .HasColumnName("PIN")
   .IsRequired()
   .HasColumnType("VARCHAR2");
```

After adding this configration query responded in `16 milliseconds`.
But it does not change the `Type=Object` to `Type=String`. It just speed up.
Thanks for all!